# swap order of text in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, swap, editing

I'm trying to swap my code (over 1000 lines) of this:

from:

```
HA09 HA(a9b0,  a8b1,         Cout09, Sum09);
FA19 FA(Sum09, a7b2, Cout08, Cout19, Sum19);
```

to:

```
HA HA09(a9b0,  a8b1,         Cout09, Sum09);
FA FA19(Sum09, a7b2, Cout08, Cout19, Sum19);
```

I've tried using this command but it's not working so far:

- Find what: `(^.*) (.*?$)`
- Replace with: `\2 \1`

Is there anyway I can swap it?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Sorry, we can't accept images of examples. Post those as text, so that we can try to solve the problem without having to re-type everything.

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\w+) (\w+)`
- If you have other characters than “word” characters `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, you can use:

  - Find what: `^(\S+) ([^(]+)`
- Replace with: `$2 $1`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  (\w+)     # group 1, 1 or more word characters
            # a space
  (\w+)     # group 1, 1 or more word characters
```

**Alternative:**

```
^           # beginning of line
  (\S+)     # group 1, 1 or more non space character
            # a space
  ([^(]+)   # group 2, 1 or more any character that is not an opening parenthesis
```

**Replacement:**

```
$2          # content of group 2
            # a space
$1          # content of group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++ v7.8.5, the following works:

- Find what: `(\w+) (\w+)(\(.*?\))`
- Replace with: `$2 $1$3`

`. matches newline` should be checked if the function definition might span multiple lines. There might be false positives; depends what language you're writing in.